# How to edit styling parameters of a PlotWidget with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

How can I edit several styling parameters of a PlotWidget in PyQt5? That is, I can't figure out how to change the title, the axis labels, grid, background color, legend style and position, ticks, scale, etc. Is there anything analogous to matplotlib's library like `ax.set_xlabel()` and all the other methods? I can't find any useful information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's tagged as pyqtgraph, I assume it's about this library and not vanilla PyQt5.

[Official pyqtgraph documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Downloadable reference guide](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/doc/build/html/genindex.html)

[pyqtgraph at Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyqtgraph)